# How to get the folder path from the given folder path?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, io

I need to search the folder whether it exists or not in the given folder path. Please suggest me your ideas.

For example:

> 1. I have provided the path as "E:\TestSource
> 2. In that "TestSource" ,i have "Sample" folder;
> 3. In that "sample" folder, i have "Details" folder
> 4. Now i provide text as "Sample".
> 5. I need to search "Sample" folder.

How to get the full path of "Details" folder?
Output:
E:\TestSource\Sample\Details.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .Net DirectoryInfo class. With this you will be able to look into sub directories dynamically. [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DirectoryInfo mainDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\TestSource");

foreach(DirectoryInfo subDirectory in mainDirectory.GetDirectories())
{
   Console.WriteLine(subDirectory.FullName);

   //go another layer deep or write a recursive method
   foreach(DirectoryInfo sub in subDirectory.GetDirectories())
   {
      Console.WriteLine(sub.FullName);
   }
}
```

Comment: The `.Name` property of the `DirectoryInfo` class will give you the name of the Directory, To get the Path you have to use `.FullName` property instead

Comment: @un-lucky Thanks.

Comment: Coool.! happy to help you

Comment: This method won't work if you have nested sub-directories

Comment: Just giving the user enough to get started they can write a  recursive function as the comment is my answers states.

Answer (score 2):

Hope that you are looking for something like :

```
string givenPath = @"E:\TestSource";
 string searchFolder = "sample";
 if (Directory.Exists(givenPath))
 {
     string pathToSample = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(givenPath, searchFolder, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x != "");

 }
```

If you want to search for sub-folders as well(let the search text be `Details`) then you have to change the `SearchOption` to `SearchOption.AllDirectories` in this case the variable `searchFolder` should be initialized with `"Details"` then you will get the output as `E:\TestSource\Sample\Details.`

Another case to consider here is, Suppose you may have `N` number of folders with name `Details` in different levels of the sub-folders then `FirstOrDefault` will give you the first found result, If you need all folders path means you should iterate through the result like the following instead for `FirstOrDefault`

```
foreach (string folderPath in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(givenPath, searchFolder, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    // iterating the list
}
```